# Teradata DBC user not able to login. How to fix it?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I was trying to enable LDAP and auto-provisioned Directory users. I successfully managed to configure LDAP with Teradata and manually mapped one user from LDAP to Teradata. This user has successfully managed to log in to Teradata with the LDAP mechanism via Teradata Studio.

Then I follow this [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Security-Administration/July-2021/Creating-Users-and-Granting-Privileges/Working-with-Directory-Users/Auto-Provisioned-Directory-Users) for the Auto Provisioned Directory. When I run `dbscontrol m g 81 T` and set it True PDA restart. Since then dbc user has not been able to log in and shows an error

`java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.10.00.14] [Error 8017] [SQLState 28000] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid. at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:302) at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericLogonController.run(GenericLogonController.java:495) at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeradataConnection.<init>(GenericTeradataConnection.java:294) at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:186) at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.<init>(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:36) at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6ConnectionFactory.constructSQLConnection(JDK6ConnectionFactory.java:25) at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:181) at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:171) at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.doConnect(TeraDriver.java:230)`

I checked if the DBC password is expired or if it's locked. This is not the case here. I tried to log in with BETQ to DBC user it was successful with the same username and password. I looked into Teradata's viewpoint it shows the same error.

I am not sure what happened here and no solution on the internet and also on the Teradata community work in here. Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Seems something is misconfigured. If BTEQ works and JDBC fails (both using TD2 with same username and password) it may be related to TLS 1.2. Try using SSLMODE=Allow (the BTEQ default) or Disable for the JDBC connection to confirm.

Comment: I don't have SSL at all and I didn't change anything related to SSL. How come it was working before and now it have issue.

Comment: I even try with SSLmode Allow still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the Logon Mechanism that you are using with the DBC user.

The DBC user does not use LOGMECH=LDAP. The DBC user must always use LOGMECH=TD2.

Comment: I am using the Teradata studious and the Mechanism is Username and Password. I used to log in successfully before in the same way but after enabling dbscontrol m g 81 T to true PDA restart and dbc through errors.

Comment: For Studio, the "Authentication Mechanism" drop-down in the connection properties dialog must be set to PASSWORD_PROTECTED (meaning TD2) when logging in as DBC.

Comment: Yes Fred, I am using the PASSWORD_PROTECTED and still see the above error. On the Other hand my LDAP use test with LDAP mechanism works very well and connected.

Comment: Then it seems you have an error in tdgss configuration that has disabled the TD2 authentication mechanism.